# Passing an object using DataContract in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, object, struct

**[EDIT] I have now edited the D with constructor and calling code in the client and OnDeserializing() and OnDeserialized() methods.**

I have a WCF service (over namedpipe), and a client. I need to pass an object (and preferably a ref of that object) as an argument of my OperationContract.

```
[DataContract]
public class D
{
    [DataMember] 
    public int Id;

    [DataMember] 
    public string StrId;

    //...


    public D(int id, string strid)
    {
        Id = id;
        StrId = strid;
        //...
    }

    [OnDeserialized]
    void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext strmCtx)
    {
    } // breakpoint here (1)

    [OnDeserializing]
    void OnDeserializing(StreamingContext strmCtx)
    {
    } // breakpoint here (2)

}
```

and this is the service contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICalc
{
    [OperationContract]
    int Calculate(string date, int count);

    // d is input of this method, and count and array are outputs.
    [OperationContract]
    int getArray(ref int count, ref int[] array, D d);
}
```

This is my client code where getArray is being called:

```
proxy.getArray(ref myCount, ref myIntArray, new D(source))
```

I have also tried this:

```
D d = new D(source)
proxy.getArray(ref myCount, ref myIntArray, d)
```

Obviously that doesn't change anything, in both cases when I receive d in the service code (code of getArray method) , all its fields are null. Why is that? Is there something that I am missing?

I know that (using enabling traces and looking at the messages at the transport layer) at the transport layer value of the fields are being correctly transported on the wire. I have also added the OnDeserialized() and OnDeserializing() methods to the object so that I can put a breakpoint there, at the breakpoints (1) and (2) all the fields are null ?!!
in fact object setters are not being called at all!!

I am running out of ideas here....

Comment: Are you sure your real `D` implementation is like shown? Maybe there is a problem with fields initialization in the ctor or something?

Comment: Thanks, Yes I have a constructor, I have edited my post to reflect that. is there now anything obviously wrong?

Comment: I'd try to add default `ctor` (`protected` as you probably don't want it to be `public`). Maybe this causes the deserialization issue.

Comment: that didn't make any diff. I still get null values.

Comment: Can you show the code where `getArray` is being called, and what you're passing as parameters? I'd like to see where you initialize `D d`.

Comment: Suggestion: Simple before complex. Try removing the `ref` and see if it works. Then start adding the `ref` back one at a time.

Comment: @Sam , Thanks, I have edited the question to show the calling point in the client code.

Comment: @John not having ref did not change any thing when I tried without ref.

Answer (score 5):

WCF is data oriented (serialized xml) and not object oriented. That won't work!

Your service operation:

```
[OperationContract]
int getArray(ref int count, ref int[] array, D d);
```

will return an data value of int. If you want to get the int value and the array value I would recommend that you create a [DataContract] for it, containing both values. In that way they will be passes as data to the client.

Calling the service operation with (ref int[]) will not make a difference.

Update with some code:
Sorry but I cant spot your error. Here is small example (that works) that you can compare with. If you still can't fix the bug I suggest you post you entire code and config.

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace WcfService2
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(InputData value);
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class InputData
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int[] Array { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public D SomeStuff { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class D
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
}

using System;

namespace WcfService2
{
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string GetData(InputData data)
        {
            if (data.Array == null || data.SomeStuff == null)
                throw new NullReferenceException();
            return "OK!";
        }
    }
}

using ConsoleApplication9.ServiceReference;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication9
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var proxy = new Service1Client();
            var request = new InputData
                {
                    Array = new int[] {1, 2, 3},
                    SomeStuff = new D {Id = 42}
                };
            Console.WriteLine(proxy.GetData(request));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that WCF cannot serialize my object on the client side and send it and on the server create a new instance of the object and assign the field values by deserialize the passed object ?

Comment: What are you saying won't work? You can certainly pass objects along, WCF will just process it differently.

Comment: @sam it not the object that is being passes, its the data, and they get serialized on the client and server side. That was my point.

Comment: @Jocke its d that I am concerned with, all the fields of d in the receiving end are null.

Comment: @jambodev So they are always null on the service side and not on the client side?

Comment: Thanks @Jocke whatever it is it must be during deserialization. I managed to enable the tracing and on the transport layer I am sending all the non-null values of the fields. But what can it be??

Comment: If you want to use constructor during serialization on deserialization check out these pages on msdn. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializingattribute.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.onserializingattribute.aspx

Comment: @Jocke Updated : added OnDeserializing() and OnDeserialized() method to the data class. fields are null!!!

Answer (score 1):

Have you got a default constructor, as WCF won't understand it if it doesn't.

Also - `ref int[] array` - arrays are passed as reference types anyway.

Comment: I do have a public default constructor, but the field values on the service side are still null, it's driving me mad. how can I enable tracing, so that I can see what is being serialized on the client side, I assume I can use SvcTraceViewer.exe for tracing ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your helps and responses.
Finally, I resolved this. As soon as I put D, in its own assembly and referenced to it both from Service and client, it all started to work.

Answer (score 0):

I had that same issue after grouping some parameters into a DataContract class.

I actually had two clients, one using a shared interface assembly with the server was working just fine.
The other client using a code copy of the ServiceContract and DataContract was not working and all members of my DataContract parameter server side were 0 or null as described above.

The problem appears to be due to the namespace in which I put my DataContract in my client.
I took care of putting my DataContract in the same namespace than the one from the master client assembly and that fixed my issue. In fact I put all my contract classes in the same namespace except the Callback one. So maybe it was not just an issue with the DataContract. Though is was working fine when not using DataContract so I guess that was the only one causing problem.

Hope it makes sense.